# Roxygen2 : S3 methods with dots in the name of the generic

Tags: r, methods, roxygen2

I would like, with Roxygen2 7.0.2, export a s3 method for t.test. But if I use @export on a function named t.test.classname, Roxygen2 writes a "test.classname" method for t in the NAMESPACE, which is not what is expected.

It writes : *S3method(t,test.classname)*

I would like : *S3method(t.test,classname)*

How to specify it clearly ?

Thanks.

Comment: I updated to 7.1.0, no changes in sight

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly classy, but I managed to do the solve the problem writing :

```
#' @rawNamespace S3method(t.test,classname)
```